# undefined reference and operator << vs me

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, undefined-reference

i'm trying to use operator << in my code but i got this error 
**operator&<<(std::ostream&, matrix)**
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
// A structure to store a matrix
struct matrix
{
    int** data;       // Pointer to 2-D array that will simulate matrix
    int row, col;
};
void createMatrix (int row, int col, int num[], matrix& mat);
int main()
{
    int data1 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int data2 [] = {13,233,3,4,5,6};
    int data3 [] = {10,100,10,100,10,100,10,100};

    matrix mat1, mat2, mat3;
    createMatrix (4, 2, data1, mat1);
    createMatrix (2, 3, data2, mat2);
    createMatrix (4, 2, data3, mat3);
cout<<mat1<<endl;
return 0;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, matrix& mat)
{
for(int i=0; i<mat.row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<mat.col; j++)
        {
            output<<mat.data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

how can i handle this problem?

Comment: You use it before you declare it. EIther add a declaration or move `main` to the bottom of the file.

Comment: Sidenote: `int** data;` can be a very slow way to make a matrix in C++. Consider using something like https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your operator defined after it is used so compiler does not know, that such operator exists at that point. You need to move definition of the operator before usage or even better just declare it before `main()` and after `struct matrix` is defined or declared:

```
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, matrix& mat);
```

note: it should use const reference, as you do not have intention to modify that object:

```
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const matrix& mat);
```

that will also make this operator to work with temporary object etc, which will not with non const reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `operator<<(std::ostream&, matrix&)` before it is declared.

Possible solutions:

- Add a forward declaration before main.
- Move the definition before main.

**BUT** as the output operator is tightly coupled to the `matrix` class why not declare it as a friend of the class? That way you are explicitly documenting the tight coupling of the output operator with the class.

```
struct matrix
{
    int** data;       // Pointer to 2-D array that will simulate matrix
    int row, col;

    // Note the output operator should not modify the object.
    // So you can pass it as a const reference in the second parameter.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, matrix const& mat)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < mat.row; ++i)     // prefer prefix increment.
        {
            for(int j=0; j < mat.col; ++j)
            {
                output << mat.data[i][j] << " ";
            }
            output << "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }
};
```